# Disabling buttons in Contextual Action bar

Tags: android

I have a UI screen that makes use of a contextual action bar.

I'm wondering whether it's acceptable to be disabling an action in the contextual bar and if it's even possible.
I do know that usually you would hide an item from the bar, that you don't want the user to currently be taking, based on the screen state.

But just wanted to check if it's a correct approach to disable an action, or else the icons shuffle around too much in the bar, based on the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recall an example of *disabling* action items in the CAB, but I have seen (and have implemented) the hiding/showing of action items in the CAB based on other conditions, e.g., selecting/deselecting rows in a ListView/GridView.

For example, the native Gallery app in KitKat will show the Share and Delete actions when at least one image is checked, and hide them when no images are checked.

As for how to do this, it depends on your situation. If you want to show/hide the actions based on whether or not items are selected in a ListView or GridView, you can implement an [AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener.html), and override onItemCheckedStateChanged(). For example, if you want to hide/show a Delete action based on whether or not any items are selected in a GridView...

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
    int selectCount = mGridView.getCheckedItemCount();        
    mode.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_delete).setVisible(selectCount > 0);
}
```